# Android RelativeLayout : Placing buttons side by side next to one another

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place buttons side by side next to one another in three buttons to one row using a RelativeLayout.

This is the relative layout placed inside a linear layout with the group of buttons

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#CC8FD8D8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="20px" >
         </RelativeLayout> 
 </LinearLayout>
```

These are the group of button found inside the layouts

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/snap"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>

                   <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/up"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/Up"
            android:text="xxxx"></Button>

                   <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_borrow"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/xxxx"
            android:text="xxxxx"></Button>

                   <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/xxxx"
            android:text="xxxx"></Button>

                   <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/xxxx"
            android:text="xxxx"></Button>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]
Please how can I place the buttons one after another in 3 buttons to one row.
Kindly assist!

Comment: Use `LinearLayouts` for this kind

Comment: I have LinearLayouts and there all aligned vertically

Comment: `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` would be so much easy. Although if you still wanna use `RelativeLayout` use `android:layout_toEndOf` and/or `android:layout_toRightOf` property.

Comment: There were placed vertically but did not stop at the third button

Comment: What do you mean by "did not stop at"?

Comment: @JnG refer the answer

Comment: Do you want Output like gridlayout ? first three in one row and 4th will be in next row ?

Comment: for that its better to use gridlayout. or use Linear layout with horizontal view and place three button in it. give weight to each button to 1. repeat for next two remain button.

Comment: @JnG Check my answer

Comment: what is main.xml . and how does it relate to layout below it containing all the buttons. clarify your aim . what do you want to achieve .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC8FD8D8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20px">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="SNAP"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></Button>
        <!--android:drawableTop="@drawable/snap"-->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/xxxx"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="xxxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC8FD8D8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20px">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="invisible"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output will be:

[image]

Comment: @JnG Thats the perfect solution.

Comment: @JnG if you think answer helps you then do upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

the following code creates 4 buttons side by side horizontally

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am upvoting this answer

Answer (score 0):

You should linear layout for this kind of horizontal buttons and don't forget to make the orientation of inside LinearLayout to horizontal.
Like

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#CC8FD8D8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:paddingBottom="20px" >
```

Then add buttons inside this linear layout, all the buttons will come side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Try `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`. Check this below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CC8FD8D8"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="20px">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/snap"
        android:text="SNAP"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Up"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/up"
        android:text="xxxx"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/xxxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_borrow"
        android:text="xxxxx"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/xxxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxxx"
        android:text="xxxx"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/xxxx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxxx"
        android:text="xxxx"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just check question again.

Comment: Please how can I place the buttons one after another in 3 buttons to one row. Kindly assist!

Comment: Can you give me pictorial presentation of how you want? Because I am not able to understand what you trying to say.

Comment: Answer wants by @JnG. I already answered it. just check image below.

Comment: Yeap .. now you got his question. Answer accepted. Just check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CC8FD8D8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20px" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/snap"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/shutterButton"
            android:text="SNAP"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/up"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/Up"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/xxxxx"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/xxxxx"
            android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_borrow"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/xxxxx"
            android:text="xxxxx"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/xxxxxx"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/xxxx"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/xxxx"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"></Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxxx"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/xxxx"
            android:text="xxxx"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"></Button>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```